# Tableau Gantt Waterfall Charts Bridge charts

Tags: tableau-api

I built a gantt waterfall chart in tableau to represent sales difference over time. I want to add columns in the beginning and end, to show the total sales before and after the sales difference occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://image.slidesharecdn.com/howtocreateatableauwaterfallchart-120307010026-phpapp02/95/how-to-create-a-tableau-waterfall-chart-9-638.jpg?cb=1376818931

You could do a dual axis to get this, with the ending total value on the second axis... *might need an LOD calc to exclude the slicing dimension for the bar on the one axis.

Or, you could create two sheets and align them side by side on a dashboard to do this.

Comment: I made use of the 2nd method you suggested above. This link goo.gl/YVbflM shall direct you to what I was able to achieve. I would need your advice on how to make the axes of the sheets uniform, else wise the visualisation gets quite confusing.

Warm Regards and thanks